# Running Python script from Java/Kotlin application on Heroku

Tags: java, python, heroku, kotlin

I have a Java/Kotlin application that runs a Python script every time the user makes a request.

It works well on my laptop and any other VPS. But I couldn't make it work on Heroku. It does not work and prints nothing.

Here is the relevant code:

```
val command = "python3 $s/assets/script.py $params"
println("Command: $command")
val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
process.waitFor()
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
val message = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
println(message)
```

Why would this fail on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku build apps based on [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). Each buildpack knows how to build a certain kind of project, e.g. one might know how to install Maven dependencies and compile Kotlin source code, while another might know how to install Ruby gems.

In simple cases developers don't need to worry about this too much. When a buildpack isn't explicitly requested, Heroku [tries to infer which buildpack it should use](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure). Basically, it iterates through officially supported buildpacks in a given order and uses each buildpack's [detection script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-detect) to see if the project appears to match that buildpack.

Once it finds a matching buildpack it stops looking. In simple cases this is often sufficient. But each buildpack is designed to generate a fairly lean image; tools that you might expect to exist on a regular Linux box won't necessarily be present. In particular, the Java/Kotlin buildpack won't give you a `python` binary.

The good news is that with a bit of configuration you can use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

1. First, set your main buildpack: `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/java`
2. Then, add your secondary buildpack: `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/python`
3. Make sure your buildpacks are shown in the correct order (Python first, then Java), using `heroku buildpacks`

   > The last buildpack in the list will be used to determine the [process types](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) for the application. Any process types defined from earlier buildpacks will be ignored.
4. Finally, you may need to add an empty `requirements.txt` file to prevent the Python buildpack from failing to run. Alternatively, you could add any Python dependencies you may have.

   If you do have Python dependencies, consider using a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` instead of a `requirements.txt`. This will cause your app to be built using `pipenv` instead of `pip`.